# reference a .css file with thymeleaf in spring mvc

Tags: html, css, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am doing a project with spring MVC and Thymeleaf. I have a question about how I should reference my CSS files if I have this folder structure:

```
src
  main
    webapp
     resources
       myCssFolder
         myCssFile.css
     web-inf
       spring
       views
         myViewFolder
           index.html
```

My configuration class is like this:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/**");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("/img/**");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/**");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/sound/**").addResourceLocations("/sound/**");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/fonts/**").addResourceLocations("/fonts/**");
}
```

And I call `href` in my index file like this:

```
href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

But there are some elements that are kind of messed up in my page, for example the CSS is not working.

Comment: It would be good if you showed the structure of your project as well as the actual HTTP request that is being made to your server for the resource

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 17):

You will need to use `th:href` attribute for referring css files. Here is a sample from thymeleaf tutorial. If thymeleaf can not evaluate `th:href` value, it defaults to `href` value.

```
<head>
    <title>Good Thymes Virtual Grocery</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"  
      href="../../css/gtvg.css" th:href="@{/css/gtvg.css}" />
 </head>
```

Comment: no what @Narresh showed you was an example of how to use th:href

Comment: Your configuration seems to be correct. however, you should have your css files in `webapp/css/` folder and you should refer to it using `th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}"`

Answer (score 6):

I have such problem!That steps helped me.

1. I have the directory /resources/css/myCSS.css. So I had put css into root like /css/myCSS.css and removed directory /resources
2. I link MyCSS like this:

`<link th:href="@{/css/MyCSS.css}" href="/css/MyCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Answer (score 6):

I used below and worked ok
[image]

here i used from css folder path .. not included static folder

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/css/index.css" th:href="@{/css/index.css}" />`