# How to load load CSS Styles in Spring Boot project?

Tags: java, html, css, thymeleaf

In `template` directory I have `index.html` with link on `static/css/style.css`. Browser not loading styles.

Same code in other static project without spring works fine. Why?
What should I do to load css from static directory?

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{../static/css/style.css}"/>
    <title>Main page</title>
</head>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping
    public String main(){
        return "main";
    }

}
```

[image: CSS ERROR]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reference a .css file with thymeleaf in spring mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996056/reference-a-css-file-with-thymeleaf-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: no, i have th:href="@{../static/css/style.css}"

Answer (score 0):

Just change your address to **../static/css/style.css**

hope its work

Comment: no! I even tried to do from other guide with thymeleaf - th:href="@{../static/css/style.css}"
and tried without it just "../css/styles.css" - doesnt work
maybe i need some dependencies or properties

Comment: please share your code image as well as library path you added

Comment: Error in browser chrome f12 -> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ("

Okey. I`ll update post now

Comment: If you are working on angular you must add the css in to json file
follow the link:
https://www.floxblog.com/add-external-css-javascript-file-in-angular/

Comment: no i am working with clear css. It is just project with 1 controller, 1 template and 1 css file

Comment: Oh man you firstly need to change the name of folder **static/css** to something else @andrew17

Comment: hmm, what do you mean? for example?

Comment: you are using directory static/css which in url means static as a separate directory and css as separate directory because slash means sub-directory jus use any other sign except slash (/)

Comment: oooo hard to understand -_-
i have 2 dirs: template and static, in template: html files(thymeleaf), in static: css and js dirs. SO i have to to delete static dir and keep: templates, css, js without static dir?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204806/discussion-between-muhammad-addan-sarfraz-and-andrew17).